# How to create button with rounded sides?

Tags: css, button, sass, uibutton

I need to create button like this

[image]

You can see a rounded borders on **center of sides**. I'm tried to do it with after and before classes, but it was tricky. Which solution is the cleanest? Also I'm done on dev resizeble button and it'll be better if this can be done as one figure, without absolute positioning or smth like that

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #F9EFCA;
  border: none;
  padding: 20px 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ae9e5c !important;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12), 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  font-size: 50px;
  transition: .2s all;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

button:hover,
button:active {
  transition: .2s all;
  border-bottom: none !important;
}

button:before,
button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 9%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 91%;
  background: #F9EFCA;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

button:before {
  left: -4px;
}

button:after {
  right: -4px;
}

button:active:before,
button:active:after,
button:hover:before,
button:hover:after {
  top: 9%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 82%;
}
```

```html
<button>Call me</button>
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/Frunky/pen/jpzELe)

Comment: Not clear on what you are asking, are you after something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qrh8710d/2/) or [this](https://jsfiddle.net/go5Lwrvb/) ?

Comment: You can actually use svg, are you familiar with adobe illustrator? It's pretty easy or google some svg online creator

Answer (score 0):

try using the property on button

```
    border-top-left-radius: 4px; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; 
    border-top-right-radius: 4px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
```

This would help you target the button corners without distorting the shape of the button itself.

Comment: 500px? how random was that

Comment: If I do it I'll get a only round button, like ellipse. I need to round a bit of center of side and more on top-left, bottom-left sides

Comment: Can you share a pic of how exactly do you want it to look

Comment: I attached it on top of the topic when I create it.
Look, please

Answer (score 0):

create a new button class and try this in your CSS:

```
.button_costum 
{  
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-size: 2.0rem;
  padding: 1.25rem 2.5rem;
  display: block;
  background-color:  // choose what you want
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: // choose what you want
  font-weight: 300;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px; // in your case it shout be 25 or 30 
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Thansk for your quick reply, but it's not I want. I need to round a bit of center of side and more on top-left, bottom-left sides